# One routine to handle multiple events in arraylist class object

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, arraylist

I want to use One routine to handle multiple events & i want to give the list class object to the routine handle clause in vb.net.

Is it possible?

I have 100 buttons on my web page & i want to handle click event of each button. I have same coding on each button but the only difference is that, which button is calling the event handling routine. So i want to make one sub routine for handling event of all my buttons. I can solve this by writing each button name in the handles clause like  -
`Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ImgRCP_26.Click, ImgRCP_27.Click,....`    . 
But it is so lengthy procedure. So that why i want to handle my button in the arraylist. How to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through your arraylist of buttons to add the handlers.

```
 For Each btn As Button In ButtonList
     AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
 Next
```

You can also add the event to the aspx part like:

```
<asp:button id="SampleButton" runat="server" 
   text="Submit" onclick="ButtonClick" />
```

Comment: I have 100 buttons on my web page & i want to handle click event of each button. I have same coding on each button but the only difference is that, which button is calling the event handling routine. So i want to make one sub routine for handling event of all my buttons. I can solve this by writing each button name in the handles clause like  -  `Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ImgRCP_26.Click, ImgRCP_27.Click,.... `    . But it is so lengthy procedure. So that why i want to handle my button in the arraylist. How to do this?